# how to create stacked histogram or dotplot in stata

Tags: graphics, stata

I have several variables with monthly stock returns like qqqret, gldret,spyret. I would like to create a stacked histogram or dotplot of them all on the same scale. any ideas how?

thanks!

ps. if i stack my vectors on top of each other and create an indicator variable for each one I could use strip plot. but i want to be able to say something like "hist qqqret gldret spyret"

Answer (score 1):

`dotplot` supports a `varlist`: see the help.

`stripplot` (SSC) is an alternative.